# 2D Animation stuck on jumping animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, 2d

I was watching an old brackeys video about how to do 2d animation and I'm confident I've followed everything in the tutorial properly. Everything was going fine until I started the jump animation. The jump animation will not stop during the on landing function. The video is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkaysu1Z-N8&feature=emb_logo and my code is this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
public CharacterController2D controller;
public float runSpeed = 80f;
float horiztalMove = 0f;
bool jump = false;
public Animator animator;
// Start is called before the first frame update
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    horiztalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

    animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(horiztalMove));

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        jump = true;
        animator.SetBool("Jumping", true);
}
 public void OnLanding ()
{
    animator.SetBool("Jumping", false);   
}

void FixedUpdate()
{        //move our character
    controller.Move(horiztalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, false, jump);
    jump = false;
}
```

}
If there is any other code or screenshots you would like me to send i will.

Answer (score 0):

In this line, you have not added the **"{}"**.

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        jump = true;
        animator.SetBool("Jumping", true);
```

Write this instead:

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")
   {
       jump = true;
       animator.SetBool("Jumping", true);
   }
```

And I have seen the Brackeys Video that you have used...
And my question is, have you added the *PlayerMovement* script to the *CharacterController*'s *On Land Event* and selected *OnLanding()* function that you've made in the *PlayerMovement* script?

Try checking that you've added the *OnLanding()* and also fix the **{}** in the line that I've pointed out.
Hope I turn out be helpful to you. <3

Comment: Yes I did select the on landing() function thank you so much for the help. as a newbie when it comes to unity and c# these things really mean alot

Comment: also after adding these brackets i still have to hit space twice for the animation to take place.